# Hosting an SQL server on Android phone

Tags: android, mysql, sql, linux, postgresql

This might seem a bit crazy and it is, but its one of those things you do just because it's vaguely possible. I'm trying to host an SQL server on an old android phone of mine to be used as a personal database. Preferably Postgresql or mysql whichever is possible (I'm not worried about the difficulty.)

I've done a little digging on Google and only keep finding results for connecting android apps to SQL databases. So what I'm trying to do is host an SQL server on my old HTC one M9 and only intend to keep it isolated to localhost and my laptop would be the one device running queries to the phone. I'd keep the physical database stored on the memory card so maybe it can be moved about. Note all data stored here is only for testing and I'd just host a Postgresql database on an aws instance after the app goes live. I know there are a few free cloud providers for testing but I'm just too hipster to do that.

Any suggestions or links to get me started on my crazy idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/how-can-i-install-mysql-on-my-android-devices . PostgreSql has no Android support.

Comment: Do you mean a RDBMS, or a NoSQL database with *some* SQL support, or anything?

Comment: @Brandon did you manage to make it work? Was just contemplating doing something similar and would like to know if any of the suggested options worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android runs Java by definition, I would think that any Java-based RDBMS *should* run. I would try with:

- [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database.
- [HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) database.
- [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) database.

My *guess* (since it's not more than a guess) is that setting up any of these just requires a JVM installed and nothing else. Since Android already has it it sounds like any of these should work.

And I have a high opinion of H2. It's a powerful engine and supports quite complex SQL.

Good luck!